# Insert and select data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert data from table sp_test with two columns; (empid and amount) into another table sp_emp (regisno,empid,itemid,year,month,week,amount,paymentdate).

This is the query I used

```
Insert into sp_emp(regisno,empid,itemid,year,month,week,amount,paymentdate)
Select * from sp_test
```

and it returned as select list for insert statement has fewer items. How should I put the values for another column?

Comment: if u want to just insert two column (i.e. empid and amount) values then also select only two columns from `sp_test` table, why you select all columns value from `sp_test` table

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
Insert into sp_emp(empid,amount)
Select empid,amount from sp_test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, using only the needed columns:

```
INSERT INTO sp_emp (empid, amount) 
SELECT empid, amount FROM sp_test
```

This `INSERT INTO` command is only working if the other columns of `sp_emp` are nullable or a `DEFAULT` value is available. If a columns is not nullable and there is no `DEFAULT` value set you have to specifiy a valid value for the column. You only need to define columns in the `INSERT INTO` column list if there is no default value and the column is not nullable.

To set a value you can add the value to the `SELECT` column list as value:

```
INSERT INTO sp_emp (empid, amount, regisno, itemid, year, month, week,paymentdate) 
SELECT empid, amount, 1, 1, 2017, 11, 40, '2017-11-14' FROM sp_test
```

Comment: Thanks! And the columns are not nullable actually. So if i want to set the value, do i need to set the value in the select statement?

Comment: @bennybenito - see the update. please also provide the `CREATE TABLE` command so we can see the data types of the columns.

Comment: CREATE PROC sp_emp regisno varchar (20), empid varchar(10), year int, month int, week int, itemid varchar(50), amount decimal(15,2), paymentdate varchar (20)

Comment: looks like your columns are nullable (you doesn't set `NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NULL` or 0 for the remaining columns.

Try the following:

```
Insert into sp_emp(regisno,empid,itemid,year,month,week,amount,paymentdate)
Select NULL,EmpID,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Amount,NULL from sp_test
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the number of columns in your source list does not match the number of columns on your destination.

For example when you are trying to insert into 5 column or a table but in the select statement or values, you have specified only 4 columns or you have given 6 columns then you will get the same error.

Here, Your Query is trying to insert values to 8 Columns on the table sp_emp and for that, you are selecting all the columns from the table sp_test. So When you are doing so you must make sure that the number of columns, There order and data type match as in the destination or else you should specify the column names instead of *. So I changed your script as below - assuming that the column names are same in both tables

```
Insert into sp_emp(regisno,empid,itemid,year,month,week,amount,paymentdate)
SELECT regisno,empid,itemid,year,month,week,amount,paymentdate FROM sp_test
```

If there is any miss match in the data type , then you can cast the source values accordingly

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
INSERT INTO sp_emp( empid, amount )
SELECT EmpID, Amount
FROM sp_test
```

Answer (score 0):

The the columns list of the insert clause must be equal to the columns list of the select clause (both number of columns and data types).

If your `sp_emp` columns allows null values, you can specify `NULL` as values. If your columns have default values, you can set them by using the keyword `DEFAULT` as the value:

```
Insert into sp_emp(regisno,empid,itemid,year,month,week,amount,paymentdate)
SELECT DEFAULT,EmpID,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Amount,NULL
FROM sp_test
```

However, a better option would be to simply omit these columns from the insert clause columns list - This will create a much simpler statement.

```
Insert into sp_emp(empid,amount)
SELECT EmpID,Amount
FROM sp_test
```

Also, as a side note, you should not use the prefix `sp_` for anything in your database. If anything, `sp_` is naturally used with stored procedures - but Microsoft uses this prefix for the system stored procedures in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate ur answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have insert only specific fields which value you have get.

Insert into sp_emp(empid,amount)
 Select empid,amount from sp_test